# long videos issue in youtube_player_flutter package

Tags: flutter, youtube, video-player

I am using this package to play youtube vidoes, but when the video is longer than 1 hour it doesn't load the video, it does not even start playing it, (my internet speed is good btw), it keeps showing the loading indicator, here is the code snippet

"

YoutubePlayer(

```
       bottomActions: [

       CurrentPosition(),

       ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),

       RemainingDuration(),

       ],

       controller: _youtubeController,

       showVideoProgressIndicator: true,

       progressIndicatorColor: primaryColor,

       progressColors: const ProgressBarColors(

       playedColor: primaryColor,

       handleColor: primaryColor,

 ),),
```

"
any solutions?

actually, I didn't try anything yet, just searched about the problem